# Core Plot CPTScatterPlot 'Line Graph' not showing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-plot

So my problem is simple. I am trying to switch my chart from a bar graph to a line graph but my line chart does not show/plot. I use similar code for my CPTBarPlot 'Bar Chart' and this plots/shows correctly.

My Bar Plot Code which plots correctly is:

```
CPTBarPlot *barPlot             = nil;    
barPlot                         = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.9294f green:0.3960f blue:0.5921f alpha:1.0f] horizontalBars:NO];
barPlot.fill                    = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.9294f green:0.3960f blue:0.5921f alpha:1.0f]];
barPlot.opacity                 = 0.8f;
barPlot.dataSource              = self;
barPlot.delegate                = self;
barPlot.baseValue               = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
barPlot.barOffset               = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.50f);

switch (graphType) {
    case kWeightThreeMonth:
    {
        barPlot.identifier  = [GraphsViewController threeMonthBarPlotIdentifier];
    }
        break;

    case kWeightSixMonth:
    {
        barPlot.identifier  = [GraphsViewController sixMonthBarPlotIdentifier];
    }
        break;

    case kWeightNineMonth:
    {
        barPlot.identifier  = [GraphsViewController nineMonthBarPlotIdentifier];
    }
        break;  
    default:
        break;
} 
barPlot.barCornerRadius         = 2.0f;
barPlot.lineStyle               = nil;
[lineGraph addPlot:barPlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];
```

My Line Plot Code which does not show is:

```
// Create a blue plot area
CPTScatterPlot *boundLinePlot   = [[[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] autorelease];
CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle  = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
lineStyle.miterLimit            = 1.0f;
lineStyle.lineWidth             = 3.0f;
lineStyle.lineColor             = [CPTColor redColor];
boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle     = lineStyle;
switch (graphType) {
    case kWeightThreeMonth:
    {
        boundLinePlot.identifier  = [GraphsViewController threeMonthBarPlotIdentifier];
    }
        break;

    case kWeightSixMonth:
    {
        boundLinePlot.identifier  = [GraphsViewController sixMonthBarPlotIdentifier];
    }
        break;

    case kWeightNineMonth:
    {
        boundLinePlot.identifier  = [GraphsViewController nineMonthBarPlotIdentifier];
    }
        break;  
    default:
        break;
} 

boundLinePlot.dataSource    = self;
boundLinePlot.delegate      = self;
[lineGraph addPlot:boundLinePlot toPlotSpace:plotSpace];

// Do a blue gradient
CPTColor *areaColor1        = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:1.0 alpha:0.8];
CPTGradient *areaGradient1  = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColor1 endingColor:[CPTColor clearColor]];
areaGradient1.angle         = -90.0f;
CPTFill *areaGradientFill   = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient1];
boundLinePlot.areaFill      = areaGradientFill;
boundLinePlot.areaBaseValue = [[NSDecimalNumber zero] decimalValue];

// Add plot symbols
CPTMutableLineStyle *symbolLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
symbolLineStyle.lineColor   = [CPTColor blackColor];
CPTPlotSymbol *plotSymbol   = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
plotSymbol.fill             = [CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor]];
plotSymbol.lineStyle        = symbolLineStyle;
plotSymbol.size             = CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0);
boundLinePlot.plotSymbol    = plotSymbol;
```

Am I missing something here? I would of thought that the datasource etc would all work the same way considering the Bar Plot works correctly. I am simply just trying to switch from a bar chart, to a line chart.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Kind regards,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was actually my own fault.

In the dataSource methods;

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

I was doing an If statement of;

```
if ( [plot isKindOfClass:[CPTBarPlot class]] ){
```

Ofcourse I was using a CPTScatterPlot so my code was not being called. Doh.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to reload your plot's data. Try doing this:

```
[lineGraph reloadData]
```

Comment: Hi skyram. Unfortunately I am already doing this towards the bottom of my code (not shown in my original post.) Its weird, I would expect the bar chart and line chart to work in a similar fashion. Not sure why the bar chart plots and displays correctly, while the line chart doesn't. The differences between the two, is basically the code in my original post. Thanks